# Are there any separatist movements in Turkey's East Thrace?

Tags: european-union, europe, turkey, secession

Once upon a time i spotted a website dedicated to the support of separatism in Russia's Kaliningrad region. The website itself was foreign-based and English-speaking. Evidently there are separatist groups in Kaliningrad's Oblast but they are not popular or supported by the majority of population.

But in their forum someone mentioned that Turkey's East Thracia could follow the same path, secede from Turkey and join the EU on their own.

As such I wonder are there any pro-EU secessionist/separatist groups in East Thrace?

Comment: "they are not popular" - IIRC, most of Germans in the area were forcibly expelled from it after USSR occupied it. So it's not like there's anyone left there to support the idea, as far as descendants of original population

Comment: @user4012 yes but a separatist movement is not necessarily targeted at Germans.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's possible since there are no more Greeks in Turkey, both because the [Greek genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_genocide), perpetrated by the Ottoman Empire, and for the subsequent [Population exchange between Greece and Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_exchange_between_Greece_and_Turkey).

There are some Greeks that still support the [Megali idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megali_Idea), that is to say the recovery of the old greeks lands, usually in the far right, but they don't live in East Thrace.

As Anixx said in a comment, in theory it's possible that there coulde be a separatist movement not driven by Greeks, but a common (East-)Thracian identity. In practice, though, given the historical hostility between Greece and the Ottoman Empire/Turkey it would be very hard to create a separatist movement in that region that isn't automatically seen as a pro-Greece movement and thus a non-starter.

Before the recent decades of economic growth there could have been some space for a urban elite against rural people type of movement in East Thrace and Instabul. Some of this divide had a role in the rise of Erdogan, who was greatly supported by the more religious rural people. But today there is a more even demographic distribution.

For the creation of a separatist movement there must be a strong unique identity and I don't see that in East Thrace.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a such separatist group in Trakia, and probably there is the last place it could happen in Turkey.

That region of Turkey is mostly ethnical Turks (mostly exiled Turks from Bulgaria, Greece, Balkans) only with some Roman population, there is not a religious distinction either with the majority (Sunni Islam), there is just much more secular comparing to the rest of the Turkey. There is no any single movement for separatism there.

In Turkey, such kind of separatist movements are only in Kurdistan region and Dersim (Zaza-Alevi people with communist ideology). Separation of the Trakian part of Turkey is just an ideology of Pan-Slavist nationalist groups, during the Russian-Ottoman war (1828) and also during the Sevre Treaty, they became a part of Bulgaria and Greece for short time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why this is the case. Especially when you can provide some sources.

Comment: @Philipp That region of Turkey is mostly ethnical Turks (mostly exiled Turks from Bulgaria, Greece, Balkans) only with some Roman population, there is not a religious distinction either with the majority (Sunni Islam), there is just much more secular comparing to the rest of the Turkey. There is no any single movement for seperatism there.

Comment: In Turkey, such kind of seperatist movements are only in Kurdistan region and Dersim (Zaza-Alevi people with communist ideology).

Comment: Seperation of Trakian part of Turkey is just an ideology of Pan-Slavist nationalist groups, during the Russian-Ottoman war (1828) and also during the Sevre Treaty, they became a part of Bulgaria and Greece for short time.